# Xcode programming

Tags: visual-studio, xcode

I wrote my programs in Visual Studio. now i have an mac and i want to program there like visual-studio. but there are differences between them. Is there any solution that i can write a code in Xcode that it is compatible in Visual Studio and works without any errors?

Comment: Unlikely. Apple supporting anything but Apple products? Ha.

Comment: @Finglass Of course, I suppose you could write VS code that is compatible with Xcode, hmmm?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any solution that i can write
>   a code in Xcode that it is compatible
>   in visual-Studio and works without any
>   errors?

Write standard portable source code. Xcode uses the GCC toolchain, VS uses MS's cl compiler. They are different. Xcode does have the notion of projects and solutions and allows configurations. However, they are a bit complicated (so beware). Also, the Xcode debugger is buggy and the editor is not as feature-rich as the VS2005/VS2008 IDE.

You can build Cocoa/Carbon based applications on Xcode but these won't compile/run on VS. Similarly, you can build Win32 applications on VS which won't run/compile on Xcode.

All in all, Xcode is your best shot at an IDE if you're not a vim/emacs fan.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write portable low level code in C/C++, but any GUI code or code which calls the OS will be non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Java would be also a good solution for platform independency. NetBeans would be my choice.

Comment: The question relates to using vs editor to create xcode, not what platform am I going to use

Answer (score 0):

Would in theory be possible to have a vs template so you go project structure and intellisense then when you build have a build script export to the mac or source repository then build on mac

Either way Xcode needs to be run on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mono and MonoDevelop, then the programs you create on Mac can run on Windows also. I use Visual Studio on my job, but my spare time I like to play around with mono on my mac. http://www.mono-project.com/